# Splitting Field of $x^6 + x^3 + 2$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

I need to decide if the splitting field of the polynomial $x^6 + x^3 + 2$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$   is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$.

My argument is that $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ is splitting field of the polynomial $x^{3^2}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$, and since $x^6 + x^3 + 2 \nmid x^{3^2}-x$ then I say that the splitting field of $x^6 + x^3 + 2$ is not $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$. Is this correct? Maybe there is a way to prove this question by extracting the splitting field of $x^6 + x^3 + 2$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ by hand but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: by the by - don't forget the freshman's dream (characteristic $3$ incarnation).

Comment: The field $\Bbb F_9$ is the splitting field of many polynomials over $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: Say, $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ is the splitting field of $x^2-2$ and of  $(x-1)^2-2$, none  of these polynomials divides another.

Comment: Thanks! I see now my argument is far from correct, any tip on how to proceed ?

Comment: @DanielBrito my 'freshman's dream" comment was a hint/tip...

Comment: @peterag oh I didn't know that freshman's dream was an actual name for a theorem, I'll try this approach thanks :)

Comment: see the 2nd paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream

Comment: Of course, it's a joke name for the fact...

Comment: Let us know whether you're OK at this point.

Comment: @markvs I think that Daniel, the OP, has in mind  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Irreducible_polynomials_of_a_given_degree.

Comment: @peterag: How do you know what "Daniel" has in  mind. Perhaps it is a  bot.

Comment: @markvs he is correct, I had that in mind, I'll try peter's approach now and see how I do with it

Comment: after using the freshman's theorem I get that the splitting field must be the splitting field of $x^2+x+2$ which is $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$/<$x^2+x+2$> which I believe is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3$ am I right?

Comment: @DanielBrito the splitting field is a field, of course, so your candidate iso to ${\mathbb F}_3 \times {\mathbb F}_3$ cannot be one of rings or fields, as a (non-trivial) product of rings is not a field; on the other hand, as ab groups (or vector spaces over $\mathbb F_3$, sure.  What is the 'usual' incarnation of the 'unique' field of order $9$ (hint look at the first sentence in your original post)?. (Alsways assuming you understand why the other option, 'the' field of order $3$, $\mathbb F_3$ is out; if not, definitely chat with your prof - and it probably wouldn't hurt to do so regardless)

Comment: @peterag Ok I understood everything now I think, thanks a lot to everyone for all the help and patience :)